# HAProxy - Request getting Broadcast to every server

Tags: haproxy

I am hosting two different application versions on same servers on different ports. In basic version i expect that following configuration should send request in RoundRobin fashion to different ports. But what i am observing is the request is getting broadcasted to ALL of my server endpoints. Meaning in below example my main request to port 8080 gets FWD to both www.myappdemo.com:5001 and www.myappdemo.com:5002... although the response send by proxy is ALWAYS from www.myappdemo.com:5001.

Can anyone tell what is wrong here?

```
global
    debug
    maxconn 256

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:8080
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    balance roundrobin
    server svr_50301 www.myappdemo.com:5001 maxconn 32 check
    server svr_50302 www.myappdemo.com:5002 maxconn 32 check
```

Answer (score 0):

i can advise you to enable logs and web interface, after that you can provide us more logs and you can check in web interface also if haproxy detects you second server(svr_50302) to be alive.

Reference to HAProxy 1.5 Doc's :
Web Interface - http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-stats%20admin

Good info how to enable login - http://webdevwonders.com/haproxy-load-balancer-setup-including-logging-on-debian/

Best Regards,
Dani